MAUI entry numeric keyboard does not accept decimal points on Android
Using a regular MAUI <Entry> with a numeric keyboard, I am unable to enter a decimal point on someone elses device, while I am able to enter a decimal point on my own device. Why is that and how do I solve this?
I'm using a simple, default entry with a numeric soft keyboard:
<Entry 
    Text="{Binding Price}"
    Keyboard="Numeric" />

With a value property bound to its text attribute like this:
private string price = "";
public string Price
{
    get => price;
    set => SetProperty(ref price, value);
}

The 'price' field originally was of datatype double and I thought this was the issue, but changing it to the more flexible string does not resolve anything.
Note: I am using MVVM and not code-behind.
Just in case this makes any difference, here's the SetProperty method I used:
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
        return false;

    storage = value;

    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    return true;
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

My own device is a Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 14, One UI 6.1 and I can enter decimal points without any problems. The other device I tried is a Galaxy S20 Ultra running Android 13 and One UI 5.1, which is unable to enter decimal points for this entry. The decimal separator button appears on the numeric soft keyboard, but it does not respond to taps.
Meanwhile I have found different devices being able and others being unable to set decimal points.
Talking about this numeric soft keyboard for Android:

The decimal separator , button works for me but not for the other device.
The thousands separator .- button does respond on both devices by keyboard clicking sound or vibrating but it does not enter any characters. If it's supposed to work by default, perhaps it originates from the same issue.
I would simply like to be able to enter decimal points (for us that's a comma symbol) on all devices, as you'd expect from the numeric soft keyboard.
Hopefully someone will be able to help me out with this.
Edit:
Changing my colleagues keyboard to a Microsoft SwiftKey keyboard (instead of Samsung Keyboard) works as in: It can enter a comma, which the Samsung Keyboard on their device cannot. This makes me believe there must be a setting somewhere for the Samsung Keyboard and it's nothing in the code. Though I could be completely wrong. Still looking for a solution.
Edit 2:
Read about other people having issues with the decimal separator for entries with numeric keyboards on Android as well. May not be the exact same issue but they are related, so I tried their workarounds. For example this thread from way back in 2022 and this other thread from this year. The workarounds appear to be outdated or don't work for this specific case.

You mention decimal points and commas, could this be a localization problem?

@stuartd Are you talking about the soft keyboards language settings? I've tried changing to English (US) and multiple other languages. None of it changes anything for my own device, nor for my colleagues device. There's a button with a decimal separator. It doesn't respond on my colleagues device. The thousands separator button on the numeric soft keyboard does respond by keyboard sound but does not put a symbol in the entry field.

I'd hook up a key (board) handler; just to see what was coming through (even if I used "MVVM"). A keyboard is a "device"; virtual or otherwise.

Do you have any recommendations for ways to handle keyboard events? Haven't been able to found one that works for MAUI Android yet. So far I haven't had any luck with the localization and language settings in my app either.

When you troubleshooted by changing double to string you should, at the very least, see input going into your model. Shouldn't your Binding be TwoWay, i.e. Text="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay}"?

After testing: Even with two-way binding, the decimal separator button does not seem to send any data at all, as if it has been disabled. On my own device everything does still work.
